# ASP.NET MVC AJAX call returning value to view from controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

During AJAX call is it possible to return ViewData, TempData or a session back to the view? does these variables are included in the cycle? please comment

```
 function submitForm(frm) {
        var tdata = $(frm).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Organization/EditOrganizationMeta",
            data: tdata,
            success: function (result) {                 
                if (result["ErrorMessage"] == "No Error") {
                    $("#" + result["DivName"] + "1").hide();
                    $("#" + result["DivName"]).show();
                    $("#" + result["DivName"]).empty();
                    $("#" + result["name"]).attr("value", result["SavedValue"]);
                    $("#" + result["DivName"]).append("<b>" + result["SavedValue"] + "</b>");
                    $("#" + result["DivName"] + "2").empty();
                    $("#" + result["DivName"] + "2").append("<b>Record is successfully saved</b>");

                }
                else if (result["ErrorMessage"] != "") {
                    $("#" + result["DivName"] + "1").show();
                    $("#" + result["DivName"]).hide();
                    $("#" + result["DivName"]).empty();
                    $("#" + result["name"]).attr("value", result["PreviousValues"]);
                    $("#" + result["DivName"] + "2").empty();
                    $("#" + result["DivName"]).append("<b>" + result["PreviousValues"] + "</b>");
                    $("#" + result["DivName"] + "2").append("<b>" + result["ErrorMessage"] + "</b>");
                }
            },
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json"
        });

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using the built-in MVC Ajax methods and scripts? If so, are you asking how to change the data in the view after executing an Ajax call?

Comment: No simply i am setting a variable in the controller , i want to retrive it in the view

Comment: Why do you need to access the viewdata/tempdata directly? Just return it as part of your JSON/XML response in your controller method. ie return JsonResult(someViewModelWhichAlsoIncludesTempData)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bsaed on the JavaScript code that you just posted, I think that the best approach would be to **return the parameters** you want the `success` function to use **as JSON**.

To return an object as JSON from an ASP.NET MVC controller ActionResult, you have to do the following:

```
return Json(myObject); //where myObject is an object that contains all the information that you want to return.
```